# Jquery document.ready function doesn't load click event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new and I was wondering if you might be able to help.  I have  come across a situation that I have not been able to figure out for the last few days.

I have a dynamic div on my document that looks like this `<div id="map_25_5">Map</div>`

In my javascript file I have

```
$('[id^="map_"]').click(function(){
   alert('hello'); 
});
```

When the document is loaded ... even if I click on the link  nothing is detected but if I use for example firebug and actually enter that in the console ... then every link start to be detected.

Has anyone run into this before?

I am using Jquery 2.1 and I have tried the "on" and "click" functions and still doesn't get registered... but when I add it to the console and run it works.  I Dont think this is an issue of using a deprecated handler with the wrong version of Jquery.

I was able to find the answer to this.  Although the original review was not correct, I am going to document this here in case someone else has this issue. This issue can be resolved by using event delegation.  Please read more by following this link: [jQuery click handler function does not fire on element added after DOM load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21193378/jquery-click-handler-function-does-not-fire-on-element-added-after-dom-load)

Comment: The element is probably not ready when the document is loaded. See [delegated event handling](http://stackoverflow.com/q/203198/1612146).

Comment: Maybe the code isn't yet loaded. Could you please post HTML of where and how the script is being added to the page?

Comment: _and actually enter that in the console ... then every link start to be detected._. Sounds like a not ready thing ;)