# How to access dynamically added element with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom

I have some posts which are coming from database.  These posts are added to page after the page get loaded by ajax. I am adding a delete button on every post and every button has an id.  Here is my code :

```
<i class="fa fa-trash" id="unique-id"></i>
```

Now I want to access these buttons in jQuery through their id on `onclick()` method but the problem is that these buttons are added in page after the page is loaded and I guess jQuery methods can only be called inside a document ready function. So currently I doing this in following way :

```
<i class="fa fa-trash" onclick="delPost('id')"></i>
```

and here is some javascript :

```
function delPost(id) {

    var post_id = id;
    var post = "#post_"+id;

    $(post).fadeOut(300, function() {
        $.ajax({

            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'update.php',
            data: ({id : post_id, act : "rem-post"}),
            success : function()
            {
                // Some Function
            }
        }); //End of Ajax
    });

}
```

I want this function to be called with jQuery... Is this possible ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery click handler function does not fire on element added after DOM load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21193378/jquery-click-handler-function-does-not-fire-on-element-added-after-dom-load)

Comment: Can you try this simple addition `$(document).find(post).fadeOut(...` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

So what you want to use `id` like this:

```
<i class="fa fa-trash" id="unique-id"></i>
```

Then, try this function:

```
$(document).on('click','.fa-trash',function(){

    var post_id = $(this).attr('id');

    $(this).closest(".post").fadeOut(300, function() {
        $.ajax({

            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'update.php',
            data: ({id : post_id, act : "rem-post"}),
            success : function()
            {
                // Some Function
            }
        }); //End of Ajax
    });
});
```

It will pass the correct `id` to Ajax and fade out its `.post` parent.

The problem with your function is not to retreive the correct `id`...
But to make a jQuery lookup using it.

On this line:

```
$(post).fadeOut(300, function() {
```

Even with the right `id`, the element you want to target **is not** in dom.

Comment: my current code is working very fine but i just want to remove onclick function foro <i> and instead i want to call this method from jquery onclick method in script.

Comment: when i will select <i> with class say .delete it will select all <i> elements with .delete class and store them in array so i must have to specify index of : 
var id= $(this).attr('id');
 to get id

Comment: I don't get your array idea. I tought you wanted an onclick fadeout and ajax update.

Comment: oh i got it man .... just excuse me as i was confused a little bit ... thanks alot your solution is working perfectly :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

Html:

```
<div class="post">
    ...
    <i class="fa fa-trash deleteButton" data-id="unique-post-id-here"></i>
</div>
```

Js:

```
$(body).on("click", ".deleteButton", function() {
    var post_id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    delPost(post_id);
});
```

I chose the "body" element to the "on" event because for it to work with dynamically added elements, it must be called on static elements, which are there from the begining. You could also use some ".posts-container" element or similar, you only have to make sure it is there when the page loads.

Comment: when i will select <i> with class say .delete it will select all <i> elements with .delete class and store them in array so  i must have to specify index of :
var id= $(this).attr('id');
to get id

Comment: You shouldn't select with the button's class, but with the "this" selector, as I wrote in the code. It should select only the clicked button.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of event delegation concept here.

Try to add events to only those images within the document with class fa-trash .With delegation it takes care of all images which are part of the dom even which are added dynamically too

check the following snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click','i.fa-trash',function(){
      var id= $(this).attr('id')
      //alert(id)
     // delPost(id);
  });
});


function delPost(id) {

    var post_id = id;
    var post = "#post_"+id;

    $(post).fadeOut(300, function() {
        $.ajax({

            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'update.php',
            data: ({id : post_id, act : "rem-post"}),
            success : function()
            {
                // Some Function
            }
        }); //End of Ajax
    });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class="fa fa-trash" onclick="delPost('id')" id="unique-id">this is del</i>
<i>hello</i>
```

Comment: when i will select <i> with class say .delete it will select all <i> elements with .delete class and store them in array so  i must have to specify index of :
var id= $(this).attr('id');
to get id

Comment: yes that's what you have to do.. In the code im trying to access the id and passing the same to a function

Comment: but how can i know that from an array of elements which element is clicked ??

Comment: not exactly clear what you are asking but when there are array of images ad when you click on an image ,you would be able to acess that perticular iamge details

Comment: oh i got it man .... just excuse me as i was confused a little bit ... thanks alot your solution is working perfectly :-)

Comment: If it is of any help consider upvoting/accepting the answer :p

Comment: yeah it's a good manner to say thanks to person who helps you but i can't record my vote as i am new user :') and i guess only one answer can be accepted at a time on stack overflow ... :)

Answer (score -1):

remove the onclick from the element, and add an id and/or class (for instance class="deleteThis" data-id="4483339").
then create an event handler in the document.ready with something like this:

```
$( ".deleteThis" ).on( "click", delPost( $(this).attr('data-id' );
```

example code to be found at http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: are you addressing with me man ?? 
if yes, i have not down vote man ... even i can't vote as i am new :-)

Comment: no not to you :) but to the person who down votes but leaves me in the dark what is wrong with my answer.